# Convert array of object in the unique array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, javascript-objects

i want to convert array of objects into the unique array from properties
Thanks!
Income data

```
const food = [
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfest: 'Tomato'},
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfest: 'Apple'}
{dinner: 'Milk', breakfest: 'Banana'}
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfest: 'Milk'}
{dinner: 'Tomato', breakfest: 'Banana'}
]
```

Receive

```
const whatIAmEat = ['Apple', 'Tomato', 'Milk', 'Banana']
```

I know i can receive it with ...new Set than concat() in separate variables, but it looks to complicated.

Comment: What would you consider not complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create an empty array (here: `result`), and then [loop over `food`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement), adding `dinner`/`breakfast` values into `result` if they're not already [`included`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const food=[{dinner:"Apple",breakfast:"Tomato"},{dinner:"Apple",breakfast:"Apple"},{dinner:"Milk",breakfast:"Banana"},{dinner:"Apple",breakfast:"Milk"},{dinner:"Tomato",breakfast:"Banana"}];

const result = [];

for (const { dinner, breakfast } of food) {
  if (!result.includes(dinner)) result.push(dinner);
  if (!result.includes(breakfast)) result.push(breakfast);
}

console.log(result);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative

```js
const food = [
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfast: 'Tomato'},
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfast: 'Apple'},
{dinner: 'Milk', breakfast: 'Banana'},
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfast: 'Milk'},
{dinner: 'Tomato', breakfast: 'Banana'}
]

const unique = {};
food.forEach(({dinner,breakfast}) => { unique[dinner] = true; unique[breakfast] = true; })
console.log(Object.keys(unique))
```

Set is still simpler. No need for concat

```js
const food = [
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfast: 'Tomato'},
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfast: 'Apple'},
{dinner: 'Milk', breakfast: 'Banana'},
{dinner: 'Apple', breakfast: 'Milk'},
{dinner: 'Tomato', breakfast: 'Banana'}
]

const unique = new Set();
food.forEach(({dinner,breakfast}) => { unique.add(dinner); unique.add(breakfast) })
console.log([...unique])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are a lot of variations on how to achieve the similar thing.

One of this ways is to traverse the array, and recreate it with groups of nested arrays, discarding the need for the object entirely, flatten it and then remove duplicates with `new Set(arr)`

```js
// Data
const food = [{
    dinner: 'Apple',
    breakfest: 'Tomato'
  },
  {
    dinner: 'Apple',
    breakfest: 'Apple'
  }, {
    dinner: 'Milk',
    breakfest: 'Banana'
  }, {
    dinner: 'Apple',
    breakfest: 'Milk'
  }, {
    dinner: 'Tomato',
    breakfest: 'Banana'
  }
]

// Implementation
function flattenUnique(arr) {
  return [...new Set(arr.reduce((acc, elem) => [...acc, Object.values(elem)], []).flat())]
}

// Output
console.log(flattenUnique(food))
```

Hope it helps!